# grep Match only exact word without being contained in another match surrounded by whitespace

Tags: grep

I have two occurrences in a file containing the string "exact match" :

```
this is an 'exact match'
this is 'another exact match' line
```

If I do `grep -w 'exact match' file.txt` I receive both occurrences.

I would like to receive only the first occurrence ( exact match).

I also tried:

- `grep -e '\bexact match\b' file.txt`
- `grep -e '\<exact match\>' file.txt`

But they all produce the undesired both occurrences.

What is the proper way of doing this with grep?

Comment: What differentiates `an` and `another` there?

Comment: Have you tried escaping ' ' characters?  `grep -e '\'exact match\'' file.txt` ?

Comment: @muru the 'exact match' is surrounded by apostrophes.

Comment: @mrc02_kr Yes I tried escaping ' ' characters? grep -e '\'exact match\'' file.txt -- it didn't work for some strange reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match the single quotes, then include these in the pattern:

```
$ grep -F "'exact match'" file
this is an 'exact match'
```

Note that I use double quotes around the pattern as a single-quoted string can never include a single quote.  Since the query string is double quoted, any shell variable or command substitution inside the string would be expanded.

Another way:

```
$ grep -F "'"'exact match'"'" file
this is an 'exact match'
```

This uses double quotes around the single quotes only, while single-quoting the `exact match` string.  Shell variables etc. in the string would *not* be expanded.

You could also use `\''exact match'\'` to single-quote the string and "escape" the literal single quotes on either side, but personally I think it looks a bit ugly.

Comment: This is not working for me because 'exact match' is contained in a "$VAR1" in a bash script. So neither grep -F "'$XX'"  nor grep -F '"$XX"' works.

Comment: @datsb What does your variable contain? Is it a fixed string or a regular expression? If it is a regular expression that should be used to query with, drop `-F` from the command.  I used `-F` in my answer because your example uses a fixed string for querying. Also, if it doesn't match, then there may be something wrong with the contents of `$XX` (or `$VAR1` or whatever you call it). Let us know what you are _actually_ trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. The `grep -F "'exact match'" file` actually worked. I was mistyping it in a rush. Accepting.

Answer (score 0):

In case of wanting to extract only the first concurrence of the result, it would be enough with this:

```
grep -m1 'exact match' file.txt
```

**-m** specify the number of concurrences and **1** means that only the first one would be shown.

Comment: Great idea. However, I actually have multiple occurrences of such lines and -m1 happens to catch the wrong one.